# Shrinkwrap sticker (image as plane) not wrapping around object

Tags: shrinkwrap

Why is my sticker im trying to place on a cylinder doesnt wrap around cylinder but leaving kind of "wings" ?

[image]

Comment: i assume that you have tried to shrinkwrap a plane? try using a circle which you extrude in z direction.

Comment: I'm not sure how should i understand this. What should i do with the circle?

Answer (score 2):

of course you can use a shrinkwrap modifier, then you should use another cylinder, delete top and bottom face and then shrinkwrap it.

Or you just use a simple deform modifier - bend - 360 degrees. So you won't need a shrinkwrap modifier.

[image]

of course you can scale the image as big/small as you want

[image]

[image]

Just change the scale in mapping.

---

[image]

Maybe you should play a bit with x scaling

[image]

and bend angle so that it fits your needs

[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE:

maybe even much easier in your case:

just use this shader:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The sticker is not supposed to connect, it's around 60% of tube diameter.

Comment: just scale down the image....

Comment: I don't understand, why scale the image (sticker) ? 
I need the sticker to fit exactly the same amount of cylinder space as in real product. Cylinder has exact size and sticker has exact size (in mm). I can't scale anything, i just want the sticker to STICK to the cylinder and wrap around it as real sticker would.

Comment: provide your blend file and i show you how to do it....

Comment: if you do it with your plane (which is shorter than the diameter of your cylider, just bend it less than 360 degrees) then it works too.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-vgdYtGCZLA

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this product: https://www.neo-angin.de/produkte/neo-angin-benzydamin-spray-gegen-akute-halsschmerzen.html

And i need to change the sticker on JPG file, so i wanted to render it on a cylinder and then just place the rendered sticker on top of previous.

Comment: thank you. unfortunately you have already changed the plane naklejka (did you apply your shrinkwrap?). Do you still have the unapplied shrinkwrap plane?

Comment: Yes, i've placed the untouched sticker into the file. You don't see it ?
Should be named as "sticker actual size"

Comment: i don't see something named sticker...maybe you deleted too much? can u upload the image too pls? thx

Comment: https://we.tl/t-jrXEjxuTLd

Sticker dimensions: 55x32 mm.

Comment: i updated my answer with updated blend file, please note that i added an empty as origin in the deform modifier

Comment: i think my shader answer might be much easier for you...

Comment: Seems perfect, love ya :) Now i need to try to practice doing it by myself.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thanks!